# What is this fluffy bug?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found this bug (actually he found me) while walking through some bushes in the city (Iași, Romania). 
It is a small bug, a quarter of a fingernail, white and a fluff tail. He lays a white fluff on bushes (that is how I meet him, I brushed the bush and got the white fluff on me, when I wanted to clean it off I saw 2 moving on my shirt) and it seems they stay around it. I also found it near the plants, on a stone pavement, but I presume he got lost.

[image: fluffy bug]

Comment: The overall shape suggests a leafhopper or planthopper of some type. I can't identify the exact species. But there are [species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planthopper) known to produce white wax structures that might explain the fluff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the image and on the description, it could be a [woolly aphid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eriosomatinae), a kind of insect that produces filaments of a waxy, cotton-like substance that gives them a fluffy appearance.

The images on Wikipedia aren't convincingly similar, but I found a better reference on [abundantnature.com](http://www.abundantnature.com/2011/10/tiny-white-fluffy.html):

[image]

[image]